# Как найти длину, толщину и центр масс кривой линии?

Tags: opencv, компьютерное-зрение

мне необходимо найти длину скелета линии, толщины линии (минимальная, максимальная, средняя) и центр масс объекта.

оригинал:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

найденный скелет (белым цветом):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно уже есть готовые решения для этих задач? или если писать свой алгоритм, дайте совет с чего начать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Длина скелета: оконтуриваете скелет, находите периметр контура функцией  cv2.arcLength()  и  делите на 2.

Толщина линии: в цикле делаете однопиксельную эрозию (объект белый, на черном фоне), считаете число связных компонент, как только число компонент из одного станет равным двум это значит что найдена минимальная толщина линии - число итераций x 2. Как только от линии ничего не останется - значит число итераций x 2= максимальная толщина линии. (можно еще через дистанционное преобразование и скелет  найти минимальную, максимальную и среднюю толщину линии).

Центр масс (центроид): или через моменты  cv2.moments cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00']), cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00']) или через cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats